# we have application on azure-Iot-edge and using azure-iot-sdk to connect to iot hub,But I'm not finding a way to enable the logs for azure-iot-sdk?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using azure-iot-sdk-csharp and I'm running in on my location. I see already some log statements are there, which has been written by DotNetty.Handlers.Logging and entire application will be deployed as a docker image and I won't see the logs in docker logs.

```
internal sealed partial class Logging : EventSource
{
    /// <summary>The single event source instance to use for all logging.</summary>
    public static readonly Logging Log = new Logging();
    public static new bool IsEnabled => Log.IsEnabled();

    #region Metadata

    public static class Keywords
    {
        public const EventKeywords Default = (EventKeywords)0x0001;
        public const EventKeywords Debug = (EventKeywords)0x0002;
        public const EventKeywords EnterExit = (EventKeywords)0x0004;
    }
   
    [NonEvent]
    public static void Info(object thisOrContextObject, FormattableString formattableString = null, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            DebugValidateArg(thisOrContextObject);
            DebugValidateArg(formattableString);

            Log.Info(IdOf(thisOrContextObject), memberName, formattableString != null ? Format(formattableString) : NoParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

any one have any Idea like how to enable the log?

Answer (score 0):

To capture logs in azure-iot-sdk-csharp you can follow instructions here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/CaptureLogs

Example of Console Logging:

1. Add `e2e\test\Helpers\ConsoleEventListener.cs` to your project.
2. Instantiate the listener. Add one or more filters (e.g. `Microsoft-Azure-` or `DotNetty-`):

   private readonly ConsoleEventListener _listener = new ConsoleEventListener("Microsoft-Azure-");
3. See the `ConsoleEventListener.cs` file to enable colorized logs within Visual Studio Code.